What are all the ways to formulate a word?
Consider the formula according to which Sanskrit and most Indo-European languages formulate the word:
[prefix] root + suffix + ending.
And now consider the formula according to which Semitic languages formulate the word:
triliteral root -> infixed triliteral root
(unlike the metaphor of concatenation with addition, there really isn't a good mathematical operation to represent the transformation of a triliteral root to an infixed triliteral root.)
What other ways are there to organize words in human languages? What subject studies this aspect of word construction in human languages?

@HighPerformanceMark It's a very heuristic formula.

‘Infix’ isn’t really the best way to describe how Semitic roots are turned into words; it’s better suited to describe how many Austronesian languages, like Tagalog for example, add specific elements in between root constituents (e.g., basa- ‘read’ → b⟨um⟩asa). Semitic roots are more like templates with slots that can be filled in using specific vowel combinations, plus various pre- and suffixes. Another common way to form words is reduplication (e.g., Tagalog basa- → babasa, Mandarin 高兴 gāoxìng ‘happy’ → 高高兴兴 gāogāo-xìngxing ‘quite happily’).

@JanusBahsJacquet What do you think is the best word for the process of a template becoming a word (e.g. P-Q-D in Hebrew becoming paqadti)? What do you think is the best word for the result of the process (i.e. the word for paqadti in relation to the template P-Q-D)?

The skeleton of constituents that is inserted into the consonantal root template is often called a transfix, so I’d call the process ‘transfixation’. More generally, different ways to form words beyond simply stringing morphemes together can be labelled under the umbrella term non-concatenative morphology.

@HighPerformanceMark ? Are you speaking about the ablaut?

No, I simply meant that the word incomplete has a prefix, in-.  Sorry to have caused so much confusion!

@HighPerformanceMark No need to be sorry. I added EBNF to cover that very important case.
